# R - Employee Reporting Structure

Tags: r, data-science

Background: I am using R along with some packages to pull JSON data from a ticketing system. I'm pulling all the users and want to build a reporting structure.

I have a data set that contains employees and their managers. The columns are named as such ("Employee" and "Manager"). I am trying to build a tree of a reporting structure that goes up to the root. We are in an IT organization, but I am pulling all employee data, so this would look something like:

Company -> Business Unit -> Executive -> Director -> Group Manager -> Manager -> Employee

That's the basic idea. Some areas have a tree structure that is small, others it's multiple levels. Basically, what I am trying to do is get a tree, or reporting structure I can reference, so I can determine for an employee, who their director is. This could be 1 level removed or up to 5 or 6 levels removed.

I came across `data.tree`, but so far, as I look at it, I have to provide a `pathString` that defines that structure. Since I only have the two columns, what I'd like to do is throw this data frame into a function and have it traverse the list as it finds the employee, put it under that manager, when it finds that manager as an employee, nest it under their direct report, along with anything nested under them.

I haven't been able to figure out how to make `data.tree` do this without defining the `pathString`, but in doing so, I can only build the `pathString` on what I know for each row - the employee and their manager. The result is a tree that only has 2 levels and directors aren't connected to their Group Manager and Group Managers aren't connected to their managers and so forth.

I thought about writing some logic/loops to go through and do this, but there must be an easier way or a package that I can use to do this. Maybe I am not defining the `pathString` correctly....

Ultimately, what I'd like the end result to be is a data frame with columns that look like:

Employee, Manager1, Manager2, Manager3, ManagerX, ...

Of course some rows will only have entries in columns 1 and 2, but others could go up many levels. Once I have this, I can look up devices in our configuration management system, find the owner and aggregate those counts under the appropriate director.

Any help would be appreciate. I cannot post the data, as it is confidential in nature, but it simply contains the employee and their managers. I just need to connect all the dots... Thanks!

Comment: In the future I would suggest providing some example example data and asking shorter question - this will increase the likelihood that you will get a quicker reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data.tree package has the `FromDataFrameNetwork` function for just this scenario:

```
library(data.tree)

DataForTree <- data.frame(manager = c("CEO","sally","sally","sue","mary", "mary"),
                          employee = c("sally","sue","paul","mary","greg", "don"),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(DataForTree)

print(tree)
```

Results in:

```
1 CEO                 
2  °--sally           
3      ¦--sue         
4      ¦   °--mary    
5      ¦       ¦--greg
6      ¦       °--don 
7      °--paul
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but when I run in against my data frame, I get: "Error in FromDataFrameNetwork(df) : Cannot find root name. network is not a tree!" Your example above is exactly what I am looking for, but my data has spaces and user IDs. An example is: "SMITH, JOHN A12345". That is the format. Is the format of the data elements throwing data.tree off? I tried your sample code above and it works fine. I'm guessing it is how my data is formatted. I am using a data frame, each column is a character vector and I have 12k rows.

Comment: Please build an example data frame like the one I made and add it to your question. Make up the data, but it should matches yours and uses the the same column names.

Comment: I did some testing, formatting you example with my data and it works with that edge case. I am wondering if it has something to do with me potentially having trees that are disconnected... In other words, I might have some organizational bodies that do not connect up to another to bring it together with the whole tree.

Comment: I'll build a data set and amend my post... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `hR` package is specifically designed to address the needs for data analysis using people/employee data; albeit, it is minimal at this point. The `hierarchy` function can produce a wide data frame as you would like; this helps with joining in other data and continuing an analysis.

```
library(hR)
ee = c("Dale@hR.com","Bob@hR.com","Julie@hR.com","Andrea@hR.com")
supv = c("Julie@hR.com","Julie@hR.com","Andrea@hR.com","Susan@hR.com")
hierarchy(ee,supv,format="wide")

  Employee      Supv1         Supv2        Supv3
1   Dale@hR.com Susan@hR.com Andrea@hR.com Julie@hR.com
2    Bob@hR.com Susan@hR.com Andrea@hR.com Julie@hR.com
3  Julie@hR.com Susan@hR.com Andrea@hR.com         <NA>
4 Andrea@hR.com Susan@hR.com          <NA>         <NA>
```