# Importing Dataframe in R

Tags: r, tree

I'm new to R so please forgive the repetitive question. I was trying to do this in Access (I know) but unfortunately the application kept crashing.

I have a dataframe object that contains 78k records that I imported from a CSV, and it should form a tree like structure, while there may not be a natural root however as this is a subset of the entire org.

```
POS_NUM|TITLE|REPORT_TO_POS_NUM
1234    Bob   789
5698    Jim   1234
8976    Frank 1653
```

This should for a loose relationship tree relationship

```
Bob
   \ Jim
Frank
```

Essentially I need this to calculate the number of sub reports for each person, the number direct reports, as well as some other recursive functions

#### EDIT

Right now I'm attempting to simply loop through my table

```
treeDataOne <- read.csv(file="File1.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE sep=",")
treeDataTwo <- read.csv(file="File2.csv",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",") #Same columns, different data
treeDataAll <- rbind(treeDataOne, treeDataTwo) #Merge data, this seems to work
#Adding new columns to store data
treeDataAll['DIRECT_REPORTS'] <- 0
treeDataAll['INDIRECT_REPORTS'] <- 0
treeDataAll['DIVISION'] <- ""
treeDataAll['BRANCH'] <- ""
treeDataAll['PROCESSED'] <- FALSE
```

I'm now trying to iterate over every record and calculate the direct reports

So I'm pseudo code it should be:

```
for i in treeDataAll{
    i.DIRECT_REPORTS = nrow(where REPORT_TO_POS_NUM = i.pos_num)
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar question. Let me know if you have any issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646041/r-employee-reporting-structure/43649124#43649124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(treeDataAll)

funky <- function(x){
  nrow(treeDataAll[REPORT_TO_POS_NUM == x])
}

treeDataAll[, DIR_REPORTS := funky(POS_NUM), by = POS_NUM]
treeDataAll[]
#    POS_NUM TITLE REPORT_TO_POS_NUM DIR_REPORTS
# 1:    1234   Bob               789           1
# 2:    5698   Jim              1234           0
# 3:    8976 Frank              1653           0
```

Comment: Thanks!  I decided to not go with R as I needed a result fast and the learning curve is longer than 3 hours.