# multilevel employee manager relationship through while loop or Reduce, base R only

Tags: r, while-loop, reduce

My problem can be considered as an extension of already solved [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646041/r-employee-reporting-structure) on SO.

To reproduce, I have multilevel employee-manager relationship in an office say, something like this

```
  manager employee
1     CEO    sally
2   sally      sue
3   sally     paul
4     sue     mary
5    mary     greg
6    mary      don
```

I have to solve this based on methods/function available in baseR only.  I tried to `merge` data with itself ( 3 times) to get results which I expect -

```
  manager employee manager2 manager3 manager4
1     CEO    sally     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
2   sally      sue      CEO     <NA>     <NA>
3   sally     paul      CEO     <NA>     <NA>
4     sue     mary    sally      CEO     <NA>
5    mary     greg      sue    sally      CEO
6    mary      don      sue    sally      CEO
```

I tried to solve it through a `while loop` but I am stuck at the point in telling loop where to stop as number of intermediate levels are not known.  I am assuming that it cannot be solved through `Reduce` or similar `purrr` functions as well due to this very reason.  I do not want answers based on 'hR`,` data.tree`, 'igraph` like packages because these answers are already available some place or another.  BaseR or tidyverse are most welcome.

dput is as under

```
df <- data.frame(manager = c("CEO","sally","sally","sue","mary", "mary"),
                          employee = c("sally","sue","paul","mary","greg", "don"),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What I tried was something like this.

```
df |>
  merge(df, by.x = 'manager', by.y = 'employee', suffixes = c('', '2'), all.x = T) |>
  merge(df, by.x = 'manager2', by.y = 'employee', suffixes = c('', '3'), all.x = T) |>
  merge(df, by.x = 'manager3', by.y = 'employee', suffixes = c('', '4'), all.x = T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the same merging solution, you can use a termination condition on whether the resultant sparse vector of managers has any managers who are also employees. This is the same as the posted code, but executed via a while loop.

```
df_new <- df
level <- 2
by_x <- "manager"
next_manager <- df[,"manager"]
while (any(next_manager %in% df$employee)) {
  df_new <- merge(df_new, df, by.x = by_x, by.y = "employee", suffixes = c("",level), all.x = T)
  next_manager <- df_new[,paste0("manager",level)]
  by_x <- paste0("manager",level)
  level <- level + 1
}

> df_new
  manager3 manager2 manager employee manager4
1      CEO    sally     sue     mary     <NA>
2    sally      sue    mary     greg      CEO
3    sally      sue    mary      don      CEO
4     <NA>      CEO   sally      sue     <NA>
5     <NA>      CEO   sally     paul     <NA>
6     <NA>     <NA>     CEO    sally     <NA>
```